# Paste thru browser native context menu for custom div

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, copy-paste

I've got a `<div>` block, where I want user to be able to paste data thru browser native context menu. `contenteditable="true"` is not an acceptable solution. `Ace editor` (http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html) is placing `<textarea>` under mouse cursor on `mousedown` event. I've tried to do the something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="editor"></div>
 <textarea id="paste-container"></textarea>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
 position: relative;
}

#editor {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

#paste-container {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 display: none;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```js
var editor = document.querySelector('#editor'),
    paste = document.querySelector('#paste-container');

editor.onmousedown = function () {
 paste.style.display = "block";
 setTimeout(function () {
  paste.style.display = "none";
 }, 0);
}
```

But I didn't get textarea's menu. Tell me, please, how to get user's paste data in that way?

Answer (score 0):

So I had find the solution. You need to set a selection for `<textarea>` on `contextmenu` event. Something like this:

```
editor.onmousedown = function () {
 paste.style.display= 'block';
};

editor.onmouseup = function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
  paste.style.display = 'none';
 }, 0);
};

editor.oncontextmenu = function () {
 paste.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
};
```